# how to get the subset of list without repetition in python?

Tags: python, list, sublist

I want to get the subset of the list without repetition of any elements in python.

For example, Mylist=[['A','B'.'C','D','E']]

I want to get the output like [['A','B'.'C'],['D','E','A']]

Comment: Do you want to get all the subsets or some specific subsets? Your question is not clear what exactly you want to do.

Comment: As an example you can check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-get-all-subsets-of-given-size-of-a-set/

Answer (score 0):

I see that what you need is a list of **permutations** of your list.

But your list should not include **nested** lists, so change the way
you defined it to:

```
Mylist=['A','B','C','D','E']
```

(in **single** brackets).

To print a full list of permutations, you can use *itertools.permutations*,
(`import itertools` needed), e.g.

```
pLen = 3     # How many elements in each list
for prm in itertools.permutations(Mylist, pLen):
    print(list(prm))
```

Note that I used casting to **list** type, as *itertools.permutations*
returns **tuples**.

But if you want only a **limited number** of such permutations,
you can achieve it using another *itertools* function, namely *islice*:

```
pLen = 3     # How many elements in each list
listLen = 4  # How many lists
result = [ list(prm) for prm in (itertools.islice(
    itertools.permutations(Mylist, pLen), listLen)) ]
```

The result is:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'B']]
```

**Other approach**, without *itertools*:

```
import random

pLen = 3     # How many elements in each list
listLen = 4  # How many lists
result = []
wrk = Mylist.copy()
for i in range(listLen):
    random.shuffle(wrk)
    result.append(wrk[:pLen])
```